# Can I use the subprocess method to pass data back and forth from Python and R without writing to a file?

Tags: python, r, subprocess

The subprocess method in python seems ideal for running an R script and also keeping R code separate from Python code.  It's pretty easy to call up an R script that does some statistics on something like a CSV file. But how do I get that R script to work on data that python has stored in memory?

I have only been able to find examples where information is written and then read from CSV files.

For example: Use python to write the string of numbers to a CSV file, then call an R script which reads that CSV file and subsequently writes to another CSV file, and finally python reads the CSV file written by R.

Comment: have you checked out the rpy2 library?

Comment: From what understand Rpy2 is similar to running R commands from python? I'm trying to avoid it because I would like to keep Python and R as separate as possible.

Comment: Still writing to file... but designed to be fast. https://github.com/wesm/feather

Comment: Not a python user, but Rserve might be a solution here. There is a python interface to it  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyRserve/.

Comment: Calling subprocesses is not the only way to keep a separation between two languages in a polyglot application. Sometimes it will not even be the best way. Regarding `rpy2`, it might do more than what you expect. Check http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_rpackages.html#importing-arbitrary-r-code-as-a-package

Comment: @cory : Feather is overkill for what I need, but thanks for telling me about it. That's definitely going to be useful in other projects.

Comment: @lgautier: I feel like I read somewhere that Python and rpy2 run into problems if the versions aren't the same. That kind of scared me off of it as well.

Comment: Set up a server and run Rserve, fastRWeb, openCPU, etc. and use R as a web service. Or access the R server over a socket connection.

Comment: @Chris : Python, R, their respective 3rd-party packages, and rpy2 all follow different release schedules and will have different version numbers. Latest rpy2 will work with the latest Python and R. For other details check http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/overview.html#requirements. You can also decide to check out rpy2 by running in a Docker container to start (see http://rpy2.bitbucket.org/).